# Change the year of a file, keeping the month and day of month

Tags: files

I have quite a few (3000+) jpeg files which I would like to the year of the creation date. I would like to keep the original date, except for the year which should be changed from whatever it is to 2013.

I tried `touch`, giving only the year to the `--date` option :

```
touch --date 2013 f1219486.jpg
```

The year is changed to 2013, but the month and day are changed to today. Using `-date 20130000` and other wildcard variants did not work.

Can I touch only the year of a file using touch (or other command) ?

Comment: Why not read the old month and old day, construct a string in the format 'newYear-oldMonth-oldDay', and then use it in the `touch` invokation.

Comment: I might have something to do with my laziness... I will try @Radu answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-t` argument instead of `--date`. From `man touch`:

> ```
>   -t STAMP
>          use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
> ```

Now, you can obtain that `STAMP` in the way you are interested using next command:

```
STAMP=$(stat -c %y f1219486.jpg | \
        awk 'BEGIN {FS="[-]|[:]|[ ]|[.]"} {printf $2$3$4$5"."$6}' | \
        sed -r 's/^/13/g')
```

Some explanations:

- `stat -c %y f1219486.jpg` will return the time of last modification of `f1219486.jpg`
- `awk 'BEGIN {FS="[-]|[:]|[ ]|[.]"} {printf $2$3$4$5"."$6}'` will change the output of the previous command in this format: `MMDDhhmm.ss`
- `sed -r 's/^/13/g'` will add `13` (curent year) in front of `MMDDhhmm.ss`

And now you can change only the year of your file:

```
touch -t $STAMP f1219486.jpg
```